# Making a gif with text changing per second

Tags: ffmpeg

I am currently trying to reproduce a gif such as this one.

[image]

But the problem I am struggling with, is in order to make a gif with text overlay I would do the following command

```
ffmpeg -ss 30 -t 3 -i input.flv -i palette.png -filter_complex \
"fps=10,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos,drawtext="fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf: \
 text='Stack Overflow': fontcolor=black: x=160: y=-1"[x];[x][1:v]paletteuse" output.gif
```

I know ffmpeg offerrs [subtitles](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HowToBurnSubtitlesIntoVideo) but I'm unsure if that could change the location of the text as well as have it display different text each second.

Do I have to make multiple images and stick them together?

Comment: ASS subtitles can be positioned with the [`\pos` tag](http://docs.aegisub.org/3.2/ASS_Tags/#\pos).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out, ffmpeg has a `between` option.  So you can specify the drawtext for durations as follows

```
ffmpeg -ss 30 -t 3 -i file.flv -filter_complex "fps=10,scale=720:-1:flags=lanczos,drawtext=enable='between(t,0,1)':fontfile=font3.ttf:text='word':fontsize=24:fontcolor=white:x=(w-tw)/2:y=(h/PHI)+th,drawtext=enable='between(t,1,2)':fontfile=font3.ttf:text='word what':fontsize=24:fontcolor=white:x=(w-tw)/2:y=(h/PHI)+th,split[x1][x2];[x1]palettegen[p];[x2][p]paletteuse" output.gif
```